# How to use python regex to extract IP address from server log files?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am currently getting started with python. I have a server log file for the pages I visited over a period of time.

How do I write a python program to find out which IP address was visited most?
Will I have to use dictionary?
I have done this but I am not sure how to use regex to fetch IP addresses.

```
import re

openFile = open('text.txt', "r")

readLines = openFile.read()
# pat = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
wordfreq = {}

for word in readLines.split():
    if word not in wordfreq:
        wordfreq[word] = 1
    else:
        wordfreq[word] += 1

print(wordfreq)

# wordList = [(v,k) for k,v in wordfreq.items()]
# wordList.sort(reverse=True)
# 
# print(wordList)
```

PS: I don't want to use counter from python module. I am figuring out to do this with dictionary.

Comment: a dictionary sounds like a valid idea, and you probably wouldn't need regex for this problem, though it would probably make the job easier depending on what the actual log file looks like

Comment: On frequency part, `from collections import Counter; Counter(list_of_ip).most_common(1)`.

Comment: I want to do it without using collections counter. i am reading from a file so i don't know where I am doing wrong. I updated my question can you have a look what needs to be done/changed?

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex and Counter

**Demo:**

```
import re
from collections import Counter
s = """www.google.com : 255.111.111.111

-some random stuff-

www.facebook.com : 255.222.222.222

-some random stuff-

www.google.com : 255.111.111.111

-some random stuff-

www.google.com : 255.111.111.111

-some random stuff-
"""

ips = re.findall("www\.[A-za-z]+\.[a-z]+\s+\:\s+(.*$)", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(Counter(ips).most_common(1))
```

**Output:**

```
[('255.111.111.111', 3)]
```

Comment: i am reading from a file so i don't know where I am doing wrong. I updated my question can you have a look what needs to be done/changed?

Comment: `ips = re.findall("www\.[A-za-z]+\.[a-z]+\s+\:\s+(.*$)", openFile.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to extract the IP addresses in addition to what Rakesh posted earlier:

```
import re

pattern = '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
finalIP = re.findall(pattern, s)
```

For the counter, refer to his answer. I just posted a different regex!

Comment: i am reading from a file so i don't know where I am doing wrong. I updated my question can you have a look what needs to be done/changed?

Answer (score 0):

To find out which IP address was visited most and this shows in ascending order. You can take 1st IP as the most visited one.

```
import re
import operator

openFile = open("text.txt", "r").readlines()

wordfreq = {}

for line in openFile:
    ipAddr = line.split(" ")[0]
    if ipAddr not in wordfreq:
        wordfreq[ipAddr] = 0

    wordfreq[ipAddr] += 1

#print(wordfreq)

# sorting the dict
sorted_ips = dict(
    sorted(wordfreq.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))


for ipAddr, count in sorted_ips.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(ipAddr, count))
```